# Which university rankings use the impact factor?

Tags: bibliometrics, ranking

As the title says: which university rankings are known to incorporate the impact factor as part of their ranking process?

Of course, I would like to use that as a negative criterion: rankings that use the impact factor are certainly trashy.

Comment: I think impact factor generalized over a university would be meaningless since each university covers many (many) fields, but with somewhat different emphasis and support. Don't overthink it.

Comment: It's best to not consider them at all.

Answer (score 2):

The three major rankings are the ARWU, QS, and the THE. None of them use the Impact Factor, which after all only applies to journals.

- The [ARWU](https://www.shanghairanking.com/methodology/arwu/2023) does not use citations directly.
- [QS](https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings-articles/world-university-rankings/understanding-methodology-qs-world-university-rankings) uses citations/faculty.
- The [THE](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/world-university-rankings-2024-methodology) uses normalized citations/paper.